# Web process failed to bind $port node

Tags: javascript, express, heroku

Heroku is ignoring my .env file for some reason, even though express shows what port to use and etc. I'm getting this error

> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds

I read other solutions that talk about removing `dotenv` but if i do that, it will crash my app. I would need dotenv to get env variables, is there way i can set an .env for heroku or what would be the best solution to deploy a express + react + postgress application on heroku ?

[image]

here is my Profile

```
web: node app.js
```

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var userRoute = require('./routes/users');
var postRoute  = require('./routes/posts');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');
var session = require('express-session');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser') ;
var dotenv = require('dotenv');
var env = dotenv.config();
var cors = require('cors');
var models = require('./models/');
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8000;
const passport = require('passport');
const path = require('path');
// const allowOrigin = process.env.ALLOW_ORIGIN || '*'
// CORS Middleware
if (!process.env.PORT) {
  require('dotenv').config()
}

// console.log(process.env.DATABASE_URL);
if (!process.env.PORT) {
  console.log('[api][port] 8000 set as default')
  console.log('[api][header] Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * set as default')
} else {
  console.log('[api][node] Loaded ENV vars from .env file')
  console.log(`[api][port] ${process.env.PORT}`)
  console.log(`[api][header] Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ${process.env.ALLOW_ORIGIN}`)
}
require('./config/passport-github');
require('./config/passport');
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(session({
  secret : process.env.JWT_SECRET,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 84,
  resave: false
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended:false})); 
const isAuthenticated = function(req, res, next){
  if(req.isAuthenticated()){
    next();
    console.log('this works');
  }else{
   res.redirect('http://127.0.0.1:8001/signIn');
  }
}
// app.use(function(req, res, next) {
//   res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
//   // res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials',  true);
//   res.header("preflightContinue", false)
//   // res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
//   res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization');
//   next();
// });
app.use(cors({
    'allowedHeaders': ['Content-Type'], // headers that React is sending to the API
    'exposedHeaders': ['Content-Type'], // headers that you are sending back to React
    'origin': '*',
    'methods': 'GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE',
    'preflightContinue': false
}));
app.use('/api/users', userRoute );
app.use('/api/posts', isAuthenticated,  postRoute );
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.locals.user = req.user; // This is the important line
  // req.session.user = user
  console.log(res.locals.user);
  next();
});
models.sequelize.sync().then(() => {
  const server = app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server is up and running on port ${PORT}`);
  });
});
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "sequelize-demo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "client": "cd ./client && npm start ",
    "server": "nodemon app.js",
    "start": "concurrently --kill-others  \"npm run client\" \"npm run server\" ",
    "heroku-postbuild": "cd client && npm install && npm run build"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "async": "^2.6.1",
    "bcrypt": "^3.0.2",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "concurrently": "^4.1.0",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.3",
    "cookie-session": "^2.0.0-beta.3",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "crypto": "^1.0.1",
    "dotenv": "^7.0.0",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "express-flash": "0.0.2",
    "express-session": "^1.15.6",
    "foreman": "^3.0.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.4.0",
    "morgan": "^1.9.1",
    "nodemailer": "^5.1.1",
    "nodemon": "^1.18.9",
    "passport": "^0.4.0",
    "passport-github": "^1.1.0",
    "passport-github2": "^0.1.11",
    "passport-jwt": "^4.0.0",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "pg": "^7.8.0",
    "pg-hstore": "^2.3.2",
    "sequelize": "^4.42.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "chai": "^4.2.0",
    "mocha": "^6.1.2"
  }
}
```

**config/database.js**

```
if (!process.env.PG_DB) {
    const fs = require('fs')
    const dotenv = require('dotenv')
    const envConfig = dotenv.config({silent: true})

    // for (var k in envConfig) {
    //   process.env[k] = envConfig[k]
    // }

    console.log('[api][sequelize] Loaded database ENV vars from .env file')
  }

  module.exports = {
    development: {
      username: process.env.POSTGRES_USER,
      password: process.env.POSTGRES_PASSWORD,
      database: process.env.POSTGRES_DB,
      host: process.env.POSTGRES_HOST,
      dialect: 'postgres',
      migrationStorageTableName: 'sequelize_meta'
    },

    production: {
      username: "root",
      password: null,
      database: "*******",
      host: "127.0.0.1",
      dialect: "postgres"
    }

  }
```

**config/config.json**

```
{
  "development": {
    "username": "eli",
    "password": "",
    "database": "elitest4",
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "dialect": "postgres"
  },
  "test": {
    "username": "root",
    "password": null,
    "database": "database_test",
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "dialect": "postgres"
  },
  "production": {
    "username": "root",
    "password": null,
    "database": "*******",
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "dialect": "postgres"
  }
}
```

**client/package.json**

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^3.9.1",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^3.0.2",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "history": "^4.7.2",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "^0.19.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.4.0",
    "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
    "material-ui-icons": "^1.0.0-beta.36",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "react": "^16.7.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.7.0",
    "react-redux": "^6.0.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.3",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "superagent": "^4.1.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "PORT=8001 react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "postinstall": "react-scripts build"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^6.2.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that `models.sequelize.sync()` is completing in a reasonable amount of time? Where's your database connection being made?

Comment: ill show you. one sec.

Comment: let me remove models.sequelize.sync to see if that changes anything.

Comment: could it be the react package.json about to update it.

Comment: i think its the react, because i removed models.sequelize, and i get `cannot get /` but when i go localhost:3000, but  the react app shows this on localhost:8001, so i need a way for heroku to use react on localhost:8001

Comment: You can't use two ports on a single dyno (and you probably shouldn't be using `localhost` in production at all). You can host your back-end on one dyno and your front-end on another. I think you could theoretically host your front-end as static files, but that likely means committing build artifacts which I don't like to do. You could deploy your front-end elsewhere (e.g. on Amazon S3), or even host your `index.html` as part of your back-end and load your front-end code from S3.

Comment: `Web process failed to bind $port node` error went away`, so the last thing to do is figure out how to set PORT:8001 on the heroku side. I know you said you cant use two ports on a single dyno. However on my localhost i can, but maybe not on heroku. So my next question would be how would i set the PORT on react on heroku ? 

thank you for your assistance so far.

Comment: You can't set `$PORT` to 8001 on Heroku. _Heroku_ sets `$PORT`, and you have to use whatever port it gives you. I think your best bet will be to host your front-end separately from your back-end.

Comment: thank you Chris, i apperciate it.

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple oversight when deploying to Heroku. Heroku manages its own env vars to keep them safe. You should not be committing your `.env` to git or any version control. In Heorkus case simply go to the apps dashboard, in the settings tab and click `reveal config vars` and put the content of your dot env in the ui. 
You can use the link bellow put your app name in there and you should see the settings screen.

`https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/<your_app_name>/settings`